# How do we form the generator of translations in quantum mechanics in curved spacetime?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

Since the generators of translations in non-relativistic QM form an Abelian group, I thought that in curved spacetime they might form a non-Abelian group. This led me to the question of how differently are generators of translations formed in curved spacetime from the way they are formed in flat space.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but it would be greatly improved if you showed some research effort. What have you read about the topic, and what didn't you understand?

Comment: Why do you think a general curved spacetime has a "generator of translations"? What does "translation" *mean* to you on a general manifold?

Comment: Probably my answer here is "there's no difference, that's the problem." The abstract core of a lot of diff.geo. is that curved spacetime is locally this nice flat Minkowski (or whatever) space, so if you have generators of translations presumably those act only over vanishingly small distances over which the space is flat. There is only one context I know of where one takes second-order effects $dx^2$ and says "secretly these are first-order in time, $dx=\sqrt{dt}$," and that is noise; you'd seemingly need "quantum noise" to pull out a second order effect and that sounds very complicated.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Well, I am now just learning about generators in non-relativistic QM and I have just learned general relativity, so I know absolutely nothing about QM in curved spacetime. I just thought that IF there are generators of translations in curved spacetime(which I again know nothing about) then they must form a non-Abelian group(that is, IF they form a group). I don't even know from where to start given my very limited background in math and physics

Comment: @ACuriousMind See my previous comment please

Comment: @CRDrost So, you say that the generators don't change provided that they only translate by infinitesimal amounts? What about finite amounts?

Comment: I'm not talking about QM in curved spacetime (both translations and their generators exist purely classically/geometrically!). I'm asking the much more basic question of what "translation" means when your manifold is not a vector space so that you cannot add a constant vector to every point and call it "translation". since unless you define that notion, it's not clear what you're asking about. Why would you think a group of transformations would be non-Abelian if you can't even define the transformations?

Comment: @ACuriousMind in very plain words, I think of spacial translation transformations as those who, when acted on a wavefunction just give the wavefunction translated by a finite or infinitesimal amount. I don't know if this is precise enough, but what I've got in mind is what Sakurai presents in "Modern Quantum Mechanics" p.44

Answer (score 1):

For finite translations, you run into a core difficulty with the curved spaces that @ACuriousMind is asking you about: finite translations don't exist in curved spaces, only infinitesimal ones exist (via choosing a vector field over the space to be the direction you're translating in). Vectors locally live in tangent spaces which are in this-case pseudo-Euclidean "flat" spacetimes, and a geometric property called the "connection" differentially connects these tangent spaces by defining how vectors are transported along other vectors.

It might help to have a concrete example: If I am on the surface of the Earth and I point in any direction (and keep pointing), then if I walk to the North pole, then I am going to be pointing South -- all directions are South from the North Pole. So I will need to identify the direction that I'm pointing with an angle of longitude when I get there. But also, travelling there depends on which path I take. So if I start at the equator pointing East, and walk straight to the North Pole, I will be pointing down at some longitude, but if I first walk some degrees of longitude to the East/West, and then go North, then I will have to add those degrees of longitude that I walked to my final result.

Locally, at every point other than the pole, North/South and East/West define directions on a flat 2D Euclidean plane and would describe how I might move around my local environment; these 2D planes however need to be knit together by some assumptions and decisions about how my motion in some direction affects the way I'm turning, and that's where the "connection" comes in. In practice you just get these components called "Christoffel symbols" which help you move from one local coordinate system to another.

Now we can ask what a finite translation even means on the sphere; it seems like you might be able to define one for East/West by using longitude, and even though the longitude coordinate is discontinuous, infinitesimally this corresponds to a smooth vector field on the sphere. But note that the translation "spacing" is a *coordinate* spacing; you say "I want to translate by N degrees of longitude" and that is not an actual distance. The actual distance that you translate by changes severely as you change your latitude. Also note that we'd have to do QM which "wraps around" this angle smoothly. You might see that the vector field needs to take priority as the coordinates we use are much further from the underlying reality than the vector fields on the manifold.

Similarly you might also be able to get a North/South translation, say by projecting every point on the sphere onto an infinitely tall cylinder. This gives a vector field which also diminishes pretty aggressively near the poles, as it must, because you can't go North at the North pole and so letting you reach that point would require admitting that our cylindrical projection is not 100% up to snuff in describing a sphere (which it can't be; they're topologically different).

So you can no longer have a translation "in this direction." Instead you need a translation "along this vector field", which might loop around on you or whatever. If momentum is to be still thought of as the generator of translations, then momentum in a general curved space needs to be relative to a choice in vector field, too. If an amplitude field a la $\psi(x)$ continues to exist, then following our general prescriptions for General Relativity, you need to first choose some coordinate fields to describe the points of the space, and the vector field you choose will map those coordinates to new coordinates, giving you a translation operator.